# Übersetzung von „should have been closed“ auf Deutsch

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive

Ich würde gerne den folgenden Satz aus dem Englischen ins Deutsch übersetzen: „**One was able to use the Wifi, even though the shops should have been closed.**“

Mein erster Versuch ist wahrscheinlich falsch, denn ich habe den Konjunktiv 2 in Gegenwart verwendet.

1) **Man konnte den WLAN benutzen, obwohl die Shops eigentlich geschlossen sein sollten.**

Der zweite versuch klingelt mir irgendwie komisch und ich bin nicht sicher, ob der Satz tatsächlich korrekt ist.

2) **Man konnte den WLAN benutzen, obwohl die Shops eigentlich geschlossen sein sollen hätten.**

Wie könnte dieser Satz richtig formuliert werden? Also mit der Verwendung von Passiv des Konjunktivs 2 in der Vergangenheit?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Antworten gehören in die Antwort Sektion und nicht in einen Kommentar.

Comment: Note: ***das** WLAN.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man konnte das WLAN nutzen, obwohl die Geschäfte hätten geschlossen sein sollen.

Comment: Or _geschlossen sein sollen hätten_, or _geschlossen hätten sein sollen_... this has surprisingly free word order.

Comment: Warum Wifi? WLAN, wie vom Fragesteller übersetzt, ist meines Erachtens gebräuchlicher

Comment: @phipsgabler, nein! Das ist ein typischer Fehler. In einer komplexen Verbform mit Modalverb, Vollverb und Hilfsverb steht das Hilfsverb (hier *hätten*) in Position 2 und das Modalverb (hier *sollen*) am Ende des Satzes. Siehe z. B. (6) und (7) in http://homepages.uni-jena.de/~x1gape/Wort/Wort_Verb_infinit_komplex.pdf

Comment: Na wenn die Germanisten das sagen...

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Auch wenn WLAN in Deutschland gebräuchlicher ist, war im Originalsatz von WiFi die Rede und genau genommen sind WiFi und WLAN nicht dasselbe. Jedes WiFi ist ein WLAN. Aber nicht jedes WLAN ist ein WiFi.