# Finites Verb vor dem doppelten Infinitv

Tags: modal-verb, subordinate-clause, verbal-complex, position

Ich verstehe, dass bei Nebensätzen mit Modalverben im Perfekt das finite Hilfsverb "haben" **vor** dem doppelten Infinitiv stehen muss. Zum Beispiel: "Er sagte, dass er leider nicht *hat* kommen können."

Ich bin aber gerade auf den folgenden Titel gestolpert: "*Grundlegung einer jeden künftigen Philosophie, die als Aufklärung **will** auftreten können.*" Hier handelt es sich natürlich nicht um Perfekt von Modalverben in Nebensätzen.

Ist das richtig bzw. notwendig? Ich hätte nämlich diesen Titel mit dem finiten Modalverb ganz am Ende geschrieben.

Darf bzw. soll etwa dann das finite Verb immer vor dem doppelten Infinitiv stehen, wenn es sich um Nebensätze handelt?

Comment: Ich kann kein Regelwissen bieten. Ich finde den Beispielsatz etwas "gestelzt", weil sie den Satzabschluss vom "will" wegzwingt und m.E. die Betonung hin zu "die Philosophie kann so auftreten" verschiebt - also das erst noch zu erreichende Ziel gewissermaßen schon vorweg nimmt. Dennoch finde ich den Satz nicht unmöglich. Würde es als "Feuilleton-Sprech" beschreiben.

Comment: Bist du sicher, dass es nicht *wird* heißt?

Comment: Diese Schrift ist 237 Jahre alt. Der Sprachgebrauch, insbesondere in subtilen Anordnungsconstraints, ändert sich zu schnell, um das heute beurteilen zu können. (Im Original heißt es im übrigen "wird" und nicht "will".)

Comment: Ich würde ja sagen, dass das umgangssprachlich sehr frei ist, wurde aber für diese Ansicht hier [unlängst gerügt](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/58483/1626), und enthalte mich daher einer Anwort :) (Björn hat mich dort [hierauf](http://homepages.uni-jena.de/~x1gape/Wort/Wort_Verb_infinit_komplex.pdf) verwiesen.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prinzipiell gilt absteigende Reihenfolge.

> laut einer Studie, die demnächst **veröffentlicht<sub>3</sub> werden<sub>2</sub> soll<sub>1</sub>**

Das finite Verb kann vorangestellt werden. Gewünscht waren Fälle, in denen ein Modalverb vorangestellt wird. Das geschieht nicht so häufig, aber man findet Beispiele.

> wie sich aus dem „Geschäft“ […] auch für sie, die beiden Anwälte, ein schönes Honorar **könnte<sub>1</sub> aushandeln<sub>3</sub> lassen<sub>2</sub>**. (SZ, 13.1.2014)
>
> Aus der Bibel wissen wir von den Plagen, die einst über Ägypten kamen, weil der Pharao in seiner Verstocktheit die Israeliten nicht **wollte<sub>1</sub> ziehen<sub>3</sub> lassen<sub>2</sub>**. (SZ, 20.4.2010)
>
> Meistens sabbele ich selber dem armen Angerufenen seine Mobilbox derart voll, dass ich es selber nicht **möchte<sub>1</sub> abhören<sub>3</sub> müssen<sub>2</sub>**. (Hamburger Morgenpost, 8.9.2008)
>
> [die Theologie] die heute bekanntlich klein und häßlich ist und sich ohnehin nicht **darf<sub>1</sub> blicken<sub>3</sub> lassen<sub>2</sub>.** (Walter Benjamin)

Was die Frage nach der Normativität angeht, äußert sich die Duden-Grammatik, 8. Aufl., unter Randnr. 684 wie folgt:

- Bei *haben* + Ersatzinfinitiv ist die Voranstellung geboten.

  > Es schmerze sie, „dass wir das aus der Opposition heraus nicht **haben<sub>1</sub> verhindern<sub>3</sub> können<sub>2</sub>**“, sagt Möller. [Welt 1](https://www.welt.de/regionales/hamburg/article200870524/Gruenen-Politikerin-Antje-Moeller-Mit-ihr-gehen-die-Fundis.html)
- Bei *werden* ist beides möglich.

  > Es deutet alles darauf hin, dass die FDP dann ihre erste parlamentarische Niederlage **wird<sub>1</sub> einstecken<sub>3</sub> müssen<sub>2</sub>**. [Welt 2](https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article169324625/FDP-muss-schon-erste-parlamentarische-Niederlage-fuerchten.html)
  >
  > dass bei den Europawahlen […] die FPÖ Verluste **einstecken<sub>3</sub> müssen<sub>2</sub> wird<sub>1</sub>** [tagesschau.de](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/faq-oesterreich-regierungkrise-101.html)
- Bei Modalverben ist Voranstellung möglich, aber seltener. Die obigen Fundsätze ohne Voranstellung:

  > wie sich daraus ein schönes Honorar **aushandeln<sub>3</sub> lassen<sub>2</sub> könnte<sub>1</sub>**
  >   weil der Pharao sie nicht **ziehen<sub>3</sub> lassen<sub>2</sub> wollte<sub>1</sub>**
  >   dass ich es selber nicht **abhören<sub>3</sub> müssen<sub>2</sub> möchte<sub>1</sub>**
  >   die […] sich ohnehin nicht **blicken<sub>3</sub> lassen<sub>2</sub> darf<sub>1</sub>**.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihren hilfreichen Beitrag