# Passiv Konjunktiv II in der Vergangenheit - Vermutung ausdrücken

Tags: meaning, verb, subjunctive, modal-verb, passive

Gibt es grundsätzlich einen Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Sätzen? Es handelt sich hier um das Ausdrücken einer Vermutung im Passiv mit einem Modalverb im Konjunktiv II.

Bedeutet

> ```
> Die Packung dürfte während deiner Reise nicht geliefert worden sein.
> ```
>
> (d. h. Die Packung ist wahrscheinlich nicht geliefert worden.)

das Gleiche wie im Folgenden?

> ```
> Die Packung hätte während deiner Reise nicht geliefert werden dürfen.
> ```

Und ist jeder Satz grammatikalisch richtig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am einfachsten ist es, wenn man neue Sätze bildet, in denen das ranghöchste Verb ausgetauscht wurde, und dann vergleicht. Die Angaben habe ich der Einfachheit halber entfernt.

> Die Packung ist<sub>1</sub> geliefert<sub>3</sub> worden<sub>2</sub>.
>
> Die Packung dürfte<sub>1</sub> geliefert<sub>4</sub> worden<sub>3</sub> sein<sub>2</sub>.

Der erste Satz enthält kein Modalverb. Im zweiten Satz drückt das Modalverb *dürfen* aus, daß es sich nur um eine Vermutung handelt. Eine andere Möglichkeit, dasselbe zum Ausdruck zu bringen, ist:

> Ich gehe davon aus, dass die Packung geliefert worden ist.

Das andere Satzpaar:

> Die Packung durfte<sub>1</sub> geliefert<sub>3</sub> werden<sub>2</sub>.
>
> Die Packung hätte<sub>1</sub> geliefert<sub>4</sub> werden<sub>3</sub> dürfen<sub>2</sub>.

Der erste Satz enthält das Modalverb *dürfen* im Präteritum Indikativ. Es drückt Erlaubnis aus. Im zweiten Satz ist *hätte dürfen* der Konjunktiv II der Vergangenheit. Die Bedeutung ist "Irrealität": Man geht davon aus, daß nicht geliefert wurde.

Die Tatsache, daß es sich bei *geliefert werden* um ein Passiv handelt, ist von allem dem unabhängig. Die entsprechenden Aktivsätze haben die gleiche Bedeutung. So gesehen könnte man auch auf einfachere Beispielsätze umsteigen.

> Das Flugzeug dürfte gestartet sein. (Aber ganz sicher bin ich nicht.)
>
> Das Flugzeug hätte starten dürfen.  (Aber es ist nicht gestartet.)

Comment: Da beide Beispielsätze ein *nicht* enthalten, muss es in der abschließenden Schlussfolgerung gestrichen werden.

Comment: @guidot Der Schluß bezieht sich auf den vereinfachten Beispielsatz, nicht das Original.

Comment: @DavidVogt Wie würde es im Nebensatz gehen?  _Weil die Packung während deiner Reise dürfte nicht geliefert worden sein, ..._ und: _Falls das Flugzeug dürfte gestartet sein, ..._

Comment: @tagesschau-zuschauer https://german.stackexchange.com/a/58545/35111 Ich würde zu *nicht geliefert würden sein dürfte* und *nicht hätte geliefert werden dürfen* greifen.

Answer (score 4):

Leider ist die Bedeutung des zweiten Satzes (beide sind grammatikalisch korrekt) eine völlig andere, nämlich etwa:

> Trotz anderer Anweisungen wurde die Packung (besser: das Paket) während deiner Reise geliefert.

Das liegt daran, dass *dürfen* in dieser Konstruktion zum Hauptverb wird.